# Extract substring from a string

Tags: android, string, substring

what is the best way to extract a substring from a string in android?

Answer (score 143):

If you know the Start and End index, you can use

```
String substr=mysourcestring.substring(startIndex,endIndex);
```

If you want to get substring from specific index till end you can use :

```
String substr=mysourcestring.substring(startIndex);
```

If you want to get substring from specific character till end you can use :

```
String substr=mysourcestring.substring(mysourcestring.indexOf("characterValue"));
```

If you want to get substring from *after* a specific character, add that number to `.indexOf(char)`:

```
String substr=mysourcestring.substring(mysourcestring.indexOf("characterValue") + 1);
```

Comment: suppose i want the index of some character in my string i can use .indexof("char"). But in my situation sometimes that character might not be in the string. then i want to get an empty string. how to handle this error?

Comment: Just test the return value first.  Something like:  
if (str.indexOf("char") > 0)

Comment: Great answer, but substring needs to be all lowercase. So it's substring() not subString()

Comment: The Android documentation is a better source: 
String substring (int beginIndex, int endIndex)
Returns a string that is a substring of this string. The substring begins at the specified beginIndex and extends to the character at index endIndex - 1. Thus the length of the substring is endIndex-beginIndex.

Answer (score 81):

[`substring()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int%29):

```
str.substring(startIndex, endIndex);
```

Comment: Simple and perfect

Answer (score 33):

Here is a real world example:

```
String hallostring = "hallo";
String asubstring = hallostring.substring(0, 1);
```

In the example **asubstring** would return: h

Comment: This answer implicitly adds the information missing from the other two more popular answers that the string is 0, not 1 based, and deserves more love than it is getting for doing so.

Comment: It is not the base which is important. substring takes a partial string starting at position startIndex and extending up to but not including endIndex.

Comment: Base not important??? It's mind-boggling vital to know that indices run from zero to string.length(), and that the last character returned is the one indexed by endIndex-1, wouldn't you say?

Comment: This is still the best answer because it shows how beginIndex is 0-based and endIndex is 1-based.  Because as bizarre as that sounds, that is how this function works.

Answer (score 18):

There is another way , if you want to  get sub string before and after a character

```
String s ="123dance456";
String[] split = s.split("dance");
String firstSubString = split[0];
String secondSubString = split[1];
```

check this post- 
[how to find before and after sub-string in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8871682/how-to-find-before-and-after-sub-string-in-a-string)

Answer (score 14):

`substring(int startIndex, int endIndex)`

> If you don't specify *endIndex*, the method will return all the
>   characters from *startIndex*.
>
> startIndex : starting index is inclusive
>
> endIndex : ending index is exclusive

*Example:*

`String str = "abcdefgh"`

`str.substring(0, 4)` => abcd

`str.substring(4, 6)` => ef

`str.substring(6)` => gh

Comment: The definition (0, 4) leads abcd which is the best answer! Will (0,0) or (1,1) show the result "a" only?

Comment: @Bay When startIndex = endIndex, it returns an empty string.

Answer (score 5):

you can use this code

```
    public static String getSubString(String mainString, String lastString, String startString) {
    String endString = "";
    int endIndex = mainString.indexOf(lastString);
    int startIndex = mainString.indexOf(startString);
    Log.d("message", "" + mainString.substring(startIndex, endIndex));
    endString = mainString.substring(startIndex, endIndex);
    return endString;
}
```

in this `mainString` is a Super string.like 
"I_AmANDROID.Devloper"
and `lastString` is a string like"." and startString is like"_".
so this `function` returns "AmANDROID".
enjoy your code time.:)

Answer (score 3):

use text untold class from android:
  `TextUtils.substring (charsequence source, int start,  int end)`

Answer (score 3):

You can use subSequence , it's same as substr in C

```
 Str.subSequence(int Start , int End)
```

Comment: substr in C++ is defined with START and LENGTH, not startIndex and endIndex:  string substr (size_t pos = 0, size_t len = npos) const;

Answer (score 3):

When finding multiple occurrences of a substring matching a pattern

```
    String input_string = "foo/adsfasdf/adf/bar/erqwer/";
    String regex = "(foo/|bar/)"; // Matches 'foo/' and 'bar/'

    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input_string);

    while(matcher.find()) {
      String str_matched = input_string.substring(matcher.start(), matcher.end());
        // Do something with a match found
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

All of The responders gave good answers. However, I am giving you all relatable methods for this so that any one can get from one place, I'll edit my answer if I find something new.

1. substring(0)- use for cut string from given specific char.
2. Substring(0,2)- give you sub string from starting(0) and ending(2) characters.
3. Split("NAME")- return you string in two parts first is that you use in split "NAME" and another part is rest of string combine.
4. subSequence(0,3) - returns sequence of give start(0) and ending index(3).

   This one is not specifically use for split string but though it may be use full for some one
5. startswith("A",3)- returns string for specific starting character.

   For example:

   ```
   String s = "StackOverflow";
   String[] split = s.split("Stack");

   System.out.println("STRING NAME:"+s.substring(2));
   System.out.println("STRING NAME:"+s.substring(2,3));
   System.out.println("STRING NAME:"+split[1]);
   System.out.println("STRING NAME:"+split[0]);
   System.out.println("STRING NAME:"+s.subSequence(2,5));
   ```

   Output:

   ```
    1)ackOverflow
    2)a
    3)Overflow
    4)stack
    5)ack
   ```

I hope this will give you enough information that you require.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to get substring in Android is using (as @user2503849 said) `TextUtlis.substring(CharSequence, int, int)` method. I can explain why. If you will take a look at the `String.substring(int, int)` method from `android.jar` (newest API 22), you will see:

```
public String substring(int start) {
    if (start == 0) {
        return this;
    }
    if (start >= 0 && start <= count) {
        return new String(offset + start, count - start, value);
    }
    throw indexAndLength(start);
}
```

Ok, than... How do you think the private constructor `String(int, int, char[])` looks like?

```
String(int offset, int charCount, char[] chars) {
    this.value = chars;
    this.offset = offset;
    this.count = charCount;
}
```

As we can see it keeps reference to the "old" value `char[]` array. So, the GC can not free it.

In the newest Java it was fixed:

```
String(int offset, int charCount, char[] chars) {
    this.value = Arrays.copyOfRange(chars, offset, offset + charCount);
    this.offset = offset;
    this.count = charCount;
}
```

`Arrays.copyOfRange(...)` uses native array copying inside.

That's it :)

Best regards!