# how to find before and after sub-string in a string

Tags: java, regex, string

I have a string say `123dance456` which I need to split into two strings containing the first sub-string before the sub-string `dance` (i.e. `123`) and after the sub-string `dance` (i.e. `456`). I need to find them and hold them in separate string variables, say `String firstSubString = 123;` and String `secondSubString = 456;`.

Is there any given String method that does just that?

Comment: It can be done but whats the exact format??? i mean is dance gonna be there always ??

Comment: @dku.rajkumar: Yep, the "dance" substring is always going to be there.  `split()` should do the trick. I should have imagined a method like this already. I thought I might have to write a regex for it. Thanks :)

Comment: then there is no need of regex, simply make use of String[] str = ;string.split("dance"); as mentioned  answers

Answer (score 52, accepted):

You can use [`String.split(String regex)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29). Just do something like this:

```
String s = "123dance456";
String[] split = s.split("dance");
String firstSubString = split[0];
String secondSubString = split[1];
```

Please note that if `"dance"` occurs more than once in the original string, `split()` will split on each occurrence -- that's why the return value is an array.

Answer (score 22):

You can do this:

```
String str = "123dance456";
String substr = "dance";
String before = str.substring(0, str.indexOf(substr));
String after = str.substring(str.indexOf(substr) + substr.length());
```

Or

```
String str = "123dance456";
String substr = "dance";
String[] parts = str.split(substr);
String before = parts[0];
String after = parts[1];
```

It is noteworthy that the second answer not work if we have more than one occurrence of the substring. To that end, if we only want the first one to be recognized, it would be safer to call split with a limit:

```
String[] parts = str.split(substr, 2);
```

which ensures that the returned array has at most two elements. Also, since `split` will interpret its input as a regular expression we have to be wary of invalid regular expression syntax. As such, I would much rather the first solution, since it works irrespective of the composition of the original substring.

To make the first answer more efficient -- as it is my preferred answer -- then, we would need to remember the position of the substring:

```
final int position = str.indexOf(substr);
if (position >= 0) {
    //if the substring does occur within the string, set the values accordingly
    before = str.substring(0, position);
    after = str.substring(position + substr.length());
} else {
    //otherwise, default to the empty string (or some other value)
    before = "";
    after = "";
}
```

It always pays to pay attention to these little edge cases.

Comment: `parts` would be a `String[]`

Comment: Wouldn't split return an array?

Answer (score 5):

If you are using commons-lang see StringUtils.substringAfter()

Answer (score 4):

Easiest is to use the `split` method as the other answers suggest. You can also use a [`Matcher`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html) and a [`Pattern`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) for a more general approach:

```
String str = "123dance456";
String splitter = "dance";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(.*?)" + splitter + "(.*)");
Matcher m = p.matcher(str);
if (m.matches()) {
    firstSubString = m.group(1); // may be empty
    secondSubString = m.group(2); // may be empty
} else {
    // splitter not found in str
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
String[] data = new String("123dance456").split("dance");
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the Scanner is a nice alternative:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner( "123dance456" ).useDelimiter( "dance" );
if ( scanner.hasNext() )
  System.out.println( scanner.next() );
if ( scanner.hasNext() )
  System.out.println( scanner.next() );
```

It is quite convenient to process the tokens as a stream and simply ask via `hasNext()` if new tokens are available. Also you get nice conversions from the `Scanner`, even localised, like:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner( "123dance456" ).useDelimiter( "dance" );
System.out.println( scanner.nextDouble() * scanner.nextDouble() );
```