# How to get a set of characters after a specific substring

Tags: java

I want to get a specific set of characters after a substring:

My substring is:

```
"Element:Neo"
```

The set of characters I want are : `Neo`

Solutions I have tried:

```
String descriptions = "Element:Neo";
String checker = descriptions.substring(descriptions.indexOf("Element:")+1);
System.out.println(checker);
```

but I got my print statement as: `lement:Neo`, instead of the desired Neo

So is it possible to use `indexof` and get just `Neo`

Links I followed: [how to find before and after sub-string in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8871682/how-to-find-before-and-after-sub-string-in-a-string) - but the given solution, didn't help me, hence I asked the question.

Comment: When you say "after a specific substring", your substring is 'Element:'" - "Element:Neo" is the whole string you want to retain a substring of.

Comment: No element neo is part of a larger substring

Comment: `indexOf` returns the *start* of the string it matches

Comment: So your actual String is something like "Some String Element:Neo", and you want to extract Neo.

Comment: `Neo` is not **after** the substring, it is **part of** your substring. How do you determine you want `Neo`, is it because it is comes after `:`, or something else?

Comment: api doc is your friend, best to study that of whatever method you are using :) Here that would be: https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#indexOf(java.lang.String)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do

```
String input = "This is a line containing Element:Neo";
String[] split = input.split("Element:");
String result = (split.length > 1)
  ? result = split[1]  // match found
  : ""                 // some default
}
```

Or, if you want to overengineer things,

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(".*Element:(.*)");
String input = "This is a line containing Element:Neo";
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);
String result = matcher.groupCount() > 0
  ? matcher.group(1)
  : "";  
}
```

Comment: Nice generic solution using regex

Answer (score 0):

If you have only one occurence of required element then you can use `indexOf` and `substring`:

```
String baseString = "Element:";
String checker = descriptions.indexOf(baseString) < 0
  ? ""
  : descriptions
      .substring(descriptions.indexOf(baseString)
        + baseString.length());
```

But if you have multiple occurences of required elements then you can use `String.split`:

```
String descriptions = "Some Element not needed Element:NeoElement:AgentElement:TrinityElement:Oracle";
String baseString = "Element:";
List<String> checker;
int firstIndex = descriptions.indexOf(baseString);
if (firstIndex >= 0){
  // remove unwanted first element
  checker = Arrays.stream(descriptions.split(baseString))
    .skip(1).collect(Collectors.toList());
} else {
  checker = Collections.emptyList();
}
System.out.println(checker);
```

Comment: The indexOf would only be needed if it's a part of a longer string, which OP did not say it would be. Also the length() would provide the proper position alone so the +1 is't required.

Comment: @Randommm where does OP state that it's not part of a longer string?

Comment: @Randommm OP never stated that it would not be part of longer string. Also I removed the +1, thanks for pointing out that. I also updated the answer for handling multiple scenarios

Comment: @daniu Well then they would need help with figuring out how long they need to make the substring too.