# how to get some particular word from String in JAVA Android?

Tags: java, android, string

I have one String

```
String path = /PravinSB/servlet/com.gjgj.rmf.controllers.Hello
```

from this String I need only word - PravinSB.

How can I do this in JAVA

Comment: possible duplicates of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5414657/extract-substring-from-a-string

Answer (score 6):

Try this

```
String path = /PravinSB/servlet/com.gjgj.rmf.controllers.Hello

String[] split = path.split("/");

String name = split[1]; //name is your result.
```

Comment: `split[1]` will contain the result

Answer (score 3):

```
String path = /PravinSB/servlet/com.gjgj.rmf.controllers.Hello
String[] split = path.split("/");
String name = split[1]; //name is your result.
```

check below link

http://ideone.com/4Uzosq

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
String path = /PravinSB/servlet/com.gjgj.rmf.controllers.Hello

String[] split = path.split("/");

String name = split[1];
```

also try this:

```
String path = /PravinSB/servlet/com.gjgj.rmf.controllers.Hello
String name=path.substring(1,status.length()-39);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure that PravinSB is going to be first item then all above answer is true. But in case even a single item is added say /a/PravinSB/servlet/com.gjgj.rmf.controllers.Hello then its going to be wrong solution.

```
String path = "/PravinSB/servlet/com.gjgj.rmf.controllers.Hello";
int indexOfString = path.indexOf("PravinSB");
int indexOfNextSlash = path.indexOf("/", indexOfString);
String name=path.substring(indexOfString,indexOfNextSlash);
```

this will work even if the string is

```
String path = "/a/PravinSB/servlet/com.gjgj.rmf.controllers.Hello";
```