# Extract substring from a string for spinner entry

Tags: android, split

I need to extract part of the string and display it in the spinner

I need that when the spinner display data example
For array entries like the following

```
"Equipo-001"
"Equipo-002"
```

Should show only:

```
"001"
"002"
```

Here's my code

```
private void rellenarSpinnerConFoliosDeMaquinasDelPunto(List<String> folios) {

maquinas = dbOn.getMaquinasDePunto(idPunto);
for (int i = 0; i < maquinas.size(); i++) {
    foliosDeMaquinas.add(maquinas.get(i).getcFolioMaquina());

}

adaptadorFoliosMaquina = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, folios);
adaptadorFoliosMaquina.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
spn_folioMaquina.setAdapter(adaptadorFoliosMaquina);

spn_folioMaquina.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
```

Comment: Unclear where you are having an issue. What have you tried to split the strings?

Comment: hi,spinner I need only show numbers

Comment: Okay, but again, `split`   exists as a method on strings, so you know what you need, so what have you tried?

Comment: when I make the split method, it marks me that this method is not available in the library java.land.string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ArrayList<String> numberFolios = new ArrayList<>();
for(int j =0; j < folios.size(); j++){
  numberFolios.add(folios.get(j).substring(8, 10)); 
}
adaptadorFoliosMaquina = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, numberFolios);
```

Check [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5414710/5512020) for better reference on how to use substring.

Answer (score 0):

You can use SPLIT function

```
ArrayList<String> data = new ArrayList();
foreach(String get:folios){
     data.add(folios.split("-")[1]); 
}

adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, data);
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Answer (score 0):

If your result will be dynamic(The string length would vary in future) the below solution may work,

```
private void rellenarSpinnerConFoliosDeMaquinasDelPunto(List<String> folios) {
    try{
        maquinas = dbOn.getMaquinasDePunto(idPunto);
        for (int i = 0; i < maquinas.size(); i++) {
            foliosDeMaquinas.add(maquinas.get(i).getcFolioMaquina().toString().split("-")[1]);
        }
    } catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e){
          e.printStackTrace();
    }
adaptadorFoliosMaquina = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, folios);
adaptadorFoliosMaquina.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
spn_folioMaquina.setAdapter(adaptadorFoliosMaquina);

spn_folioMaquina.setOnItemSelectedListener(new  AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
```