# get word after a specific string androidstudio

Tags: java, android-studio

my problem is that I have a string called url which has an extructure like the following https://www.ejemplo.com.co, and I need to extract only the text after "https: // www.", that is what I serves is "ejemplo.com.co", of course I do not know the url as it changes constantly.

Comment: Hint: look at the `split` and `substring` methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following:

```
    public String retrieveStr(String url) throws MalformedURLException {
       URL aURL = new URL(url);
       String desireStr  = aURL.getHost().split("\\.")[1];
      return desireStr;
  }
```

use this

Comment: Thank you very much, but I would miss a part, taking into account that I already have after the puneto, as I do to only hold the part after the next point. I mean what would happen before the point, eg: ejemplo.com.co, I just want "example"

Comment: you mean "ejemplo"? Do you want only "ejemplo" , please clarify

Comment: yes, let's give a practical example, this is the url: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5414657/, what I want to know is "stackoverflow"

Comment: use the updated code in the answer box. Hope this will work :-)

Comment: Good to know it works.. please upvote the answer :-).