# is there any way to choose more than 1 character by using charAt()

Tags: android

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        TextView txt1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt1);
        TextView txt2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt2);
        TextView txt3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt3);
        TextView txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt4);
        String myStringValue = "Android programming is fun.";
        txt1.setText(myStringValue);
        txt2.setText(myStringValue.charAt(0) + "");
    }
```

i want to choose more than one character in charAt().

Comment: No. **charAt** takes one and only one character. But you can still extract a substring out of a string.

Comment: No, then it wouldn't return a char. You could try getting a sub string if you wanted multiple characters. What are you trying to achieve exactly?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Extract substring from a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5414657/extract-substring-from-a-string)

Answer (score 0):

charAt() always return one char. if you want more you must use other method or create loop for you purpose.

For example

```
    String myStringValue = "Android programming is fun.";
    StringBuilder textViewText = new StringBuilder();
    for(int i = 0 ; i< myStringValue.length();i++){
        if (i>=24 && i<=26){
            textViewText.append(myStringValue.charAt(i));
        }
    }
    Log.i("test",textViewText.toString());//print fun
```

Or use [`substring`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int%29) method

```
txt2.setText(myStringValue.substring(24,26) + "");//print fun
```